# Formula for diminishing returns

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, regression

How would you go about finding a formula for diminishing returns that matches this (wasnt sure on the tag either, apologies if it does not fit but it wasnt a linear equation that I could figure out so it might be differential?):

```
4.0    1
3.7    2
3.5    3
3.16   4
2.9    5
2.74   6
2.56   7
2.4    8
2.255  9
2.12   10
2      11
1.88   12
1.786  13
1.692  14
1.6    15
1.52   16
1.45   17
1.38   18
1.31   19
1.257  20
```

Comment: Which column is the input and which column is the output?

Comment: I'd try something like an inverse quadratic. This matches pretty closely: $f(n) = 1/(0.0004 n^2 + 0.0204 n + 0.2276)$

Comment: Another fit: $f(n)=\exp(1.46595-0.0813884\,n+0.000987708\,n^2)$ obtained by fitting $(n,\ln(y_n))$ to a quadratic function.